# sort array of object of array key value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to sort an array of objects of array for nvd3 chart in typescript with no luck, any help on this is appreciated,

the data looks something like this,

```
[
 {"k": "Name1", "val": [{"s": 33, "d": "sa"}, {"s": 1, "d": "as"}, {"s": 56, "d": "te"}]}
 {"k": "Name2", "val": [{"s": 31, "d": "re"}, {"s": 4, "d": "sa"}, {"s": 1, "d": "ba"}]}
]
```

The output should be something below,

```
[
 {"k": "Name1", "val": [{"s": 1, "d": "as"}, {"s": 33, "d": "sa"}, {"s": 56, "d": "te"}]}
 {"k": "Name2", "val": [{"s": 1, "d": "ba"}, {"s": 4, "d": "sa"}, {"s": 31, "d": "re"}]}
]
```

I tried doing something like this with no luck,

```
arr=[
 {"k": "Name1", "val": [{"s": 33, "d": "sa"}, {"s": 1, "d": "as"}, {"s": 56, "d": "te"}]}
 {"k": "Name2", "val": [{"s": 31, "d": "re"}, {"s": 4, "d": "sa"}, {"s": 1, "d": "ba"}]}
]

arr.sort((a,b) => (a.s > b.s) ? 1 : ((b.s > a.s) ? -1 : 0));
```

any help on this is really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the "val" key in the array be sorted right?. So this is what you have to do it.

```
arr.map( (element) => element.val.sort(
   (a,b) => (a.s > b.s) ? 1 : ((b.s > a.s) ? -1 : 0)) 
);
```

Comment: FYI `Array#sort` is in place

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using `reduce` and [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) together

```js
const input = [
 {"k": "Name1", "val": [{"s": 33, "d": "sa"}, {"s": 1, "d": "as"}, {"s": 56, "d": "te"}]},
 {"k": "Name2", "val": [{"s": 31, "d": "re"}, {"s": 4, "d": "sa"}, {"s": 1, "d": "ba"}]}
];

const output = input.reduce( (prev, element) => {
  const item = element;
  Object.assign({}, item, {val: element.val.sort((a,b) => a.s- b.s)});
  return prev.concat(item);

},[])

console.log({output});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `forEach` as it doesn't return a result like `map` and `reduce`, effectively resorting your array in place.

#### Solution

```js
const data = [
 {"k": "Name1", "val": [{"s": 33, "d": "sa"}, {"s": 1, "d": "as"}, {"s": 56, "d": "te"}]},
 {"k": "Name2", "val": [{"s": 31, "d": "re"}, {"s": 4, "d": "sa"}, {"s": 1, "d": "ba"}]}
]

data.forEach(obj => {
  obj.val.sort((a, b) => a.s - b.s);
})

console.log(data)
```

#### Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Return_value

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Return_value

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Return_value

Comment: IMO, this is not a good approach. we must use pure functions which to avoid mutation of original data. read more about the importance of [Immutability](https://hackernoon.com/immutability-that-is-the-question-3d2dc4c2e029)

Comment: @diEcho OP didn't indicate they wanted immutability, and if their object is huge, `map` will have detrimental effects on space-complexity by duplicating the entire object wastefully.

Comment: we must encourage to better javascript writing. additional knowledge is not harmful. maybe the user is not aware of the immutability at all.